# No Me Deja Mostrar Una Imagen Guardada En MongoDB Con Una Plantilla

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, imagen, handlebars

**¿Cual Es El Problema?**
he estado tratando de mostrar una imagen guardada desde mi base de datos con una plantilla llamada Handlebars el problema es que no se muestra la imagen estoy usando node.js para enviar el objeto a la plantilla.

**Archivo Node.js**

```
const ctrl = {};
const { Image } = require('../models'); //Requerimos La Estructura de un archivo index.js que esta en una caperta llamada modules

ctrl.index = async (req,res) => {
  const images = await Image.find().sort({timeStamp: -1});
  res.render('index', { images }); //aquí le estamos pasando el objeto images en el cual estamos buscando en un esquema de mongodb llamado Images
};

module.exports = ctrl;
```

este es el que envía el dato al html a través de un objeto llamado images que es una variable que ya cree

**Estructura De MongoDB**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const path = require('path');

const DataImage = new Schema({
   title: { type: String, required: true },
   description: { type: String, required: false },
   fielName: { type: String }, //esta parte del código es lo que voy a utilizar mas adelante para llamar a la imagen
   views: { type: Number, default: 0 },
   like: { type: Number, default: 0 },
   timeStamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
 }); //creamos el esquema

DataImage.virtual('uniqueId')
   .get(function (){
       return this.fielName.replace(path.extname(this.fielName), ''); //Aquí lo que hago es quitarle las extensiones de la imagen para que no aparezca en la url osea el .jpg .png etc
});

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', DataImage);
```

Aquí defino como sera mi esquema en mongoDb esto lo exporto al siguiente código

**Archivo Base Para La Funcionalidad Del Codigo**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const { randomName } = require('../helpers/libs'); //solo quiero su biblioteca randomName Esto es para las URL aleatorias

const { Image } = require('../models'); //Aqui requerimos el esquema Image

const ctrl = {};

ctrl.create = (req,res) => {
   const saveImage = async () => {
       const URLImage = randomName();
       const images = await Image.find({ fielName: URLImage }) //busca en todas las imagenes
    if (images.length > 0){ //Si has encontrado un archivo con el mismo nombre has lo siguiente
        saveImage(); //no va a seguir con el código si no que se va a repetir para buscar otra URL aleatoria que ya he creado
    } else {
        const directionImageTemp = req.file.path; //busco la direccion de la imagen
        const ext = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase(); //aquí extraigo la extensión o el .png etc a minúsculas pero lo extraigo en una variable aparte
        const targetPath = path.resolve(`src/public/upload/${URLImage}${ext}`);
        if (ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.png' || ext === 'jpeg' || ext === 'gif' || ext === '.tiff' || ext === '.psd' || ext === '.bmp' || ext === '.mp4' || ext === '.avi' || ext === '.mkv' || ext === '.flv' || ext === '.mov' || ext === 'wmv' || ext === '.divx') { //Estos son los archivos que voy a admitir
            await fs.rename(directionImageTemp, targetPath); //mueve un archivo de un directorio a otro //primero le digo donde se encuentra el archivo y luego donde lo voy a mover
            const newImage = new Image({
                title: req.body.title,
                fielName: URLImage + ext,
                description: req.body.description
            });
            console.log(newImage.fielName);
            const imageSaved = await newImage.save(); //guardamos la imagen en la base de datos
            res.send('BUENO! Subida De Imagen Exitosa / OKAY! Successful Images Upload');
        } else {
            await fs.unlink(directionImageTemp); //Para eliminar la imagen con una direccion que ya definimos
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'El Formato Del Archivo No Esta Permitido' });
        };
    };
};
   saveImage();
};

  module.exports = ctrl;
```

Este es el corazón de mi código aquí podemos guardar las imágenes que creamos esto genera un nombre aleatorio en el cual se mostrara en la url cuando el usuario visite una pagina

**Html Con Handlerbars**

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">
            <i class="fas fa-music"></i> Carga Una Imagen O Video <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="/image" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Escoja Una Imagen</h3>
                <label for="input-group" class="label-search"></label>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="input-file" id="input-group" required>
                <label for="input-group" class="label-input">Buscar</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titulo De La Imagen" required class="input-form" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="description" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion (Opcional)"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i>Publicar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header text-align-left">
        <h3><i class="fas fa-images"></i>Subidas Recientemente<i class="fas fa-music"></i></h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            {{#each images}}
                <div class="col4">
                    <a href="/image/{{uniqueId}}"><!--Esto no me funciona esto es para que en la URL aparezca el nombre aleatorio que le puse sin la extension-->
                        <img src="/public/upload/{{images}}" class="w-100 h-100 b-r-15"> <!--Aqui es donde quiero mostrar la imagen llamando la variable del archivo de node.js-->
                    </a>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

este es el problema el archivo aparentemente no lo toma en cuenta haciendo que no se suba la imagen ni tampoco la url creada
Por favor si alguien me podría ayudar con este problema se los agradecería :,(

Comment: En tu html al no tener una imagen de aparecerá un icono, habré ese icono en una nueva pestaña y verifica que la URL sea correcta

Comment: muchas gracias bro, me podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: si te aparece un icono en tu html en vez de la imagen, sola dale click derecho y seleccionas *abrir enlace en una nueva ventana* si no te aparece a tu etiqueta **img** ponle el atributo **alt** de esta forma ```alt="mi-imagen"```, y sigues el mismo paso, luego de eso verificas la url que aparece arriba

Comment: como pudiste resolver ese error?